# I used payable function for fund transfer but getting revert transaction error

Tags: solidity, payable

Function which I try to executre

```
function executeSale(
    uint256 tokenId,
    address _account
) public payable {
    uint price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
    address seller = idToListedToken[tokenId].seller;
    // Marketplace owner get the listing fee in every sale
    require(_account.balance >= price , "You have enough money to buy this NFT");
    //update the details of the token
    idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
    idToListedToken[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
    _itemsSold.increment();
    //Actually transfer the token to the new owner
    _transfer(seller, msg.sender, tokenId);
    //approve the marketplace to sell NFTs on your behalf
    approve(seller, tokenId);

    //Transfer the listing fee to the marketplace creator
    payable(owner).transfer(listPrice);

    //Transfer the proceeds from the sale to the seller of the NFT
    payable(seller).transfer(price);

}
```

got error
[image]

Comment: Based on the image the value you sent was 0 wei. Require should probably check the msg.value, and return string may be better to say that there isn't enough to buy. The contract won't be able to move other peoples ether from their accounts. It should be sent with the call or people should approve the contract to move a token that the contract then transfers.

Comment: but I didn't use msg.value in the whole code bro